# Writing to docx using xceed.words.net.docx, works when run in VS, writes a line per page when run as built exe

Tags: c#, .net, docx, xceed

I've been using this for a while and it's always worked fine. The project writes to a docx log file as it runs. I recently made a modification to the path it writes the log to for someone else to use. Since then, when I run it as a built exe it writes one line per page. But when I attempt to fix the problem, I can't recreate it running it in VS. From there it works like it always had.

Any ideas? A direction someone can point me toward?

```
        public static void WritetoLogFile(string logUpdate)
    {
        DateTime now            = DateTime.Now;
        string logDate          = now.ToString("MM-dd");
        string folderNameDate   = now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy");
        string folderName       = folderNameDate + "_Logs";
        string stateFolder      = " ";

        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Crawlspace.networkSharePath + "//" + folderName);

        string logName = logDate + "_" + Crawlspace.browser + "_" + Crawlspace.computerName + "_" + Crawlspace.SuiteTable + ".docx";
        Crawlspace.LogFileName = logName;


        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Crawlspace.networkSharePath + folderName + "//" + stateFolder);

        Crawlspace.LogFile = Crawlspace.networkSharePath + folderName + "//" + stateFolder + "//" + logName;

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Crawlspace.LogFile))
        {
            using (DocX document = DocX.Load(Crawlspace.LogFile))
            {
                Paragraph par1 = document.InsertParagraph();
                par1.Append(logUpdate);
                par1.Font("Courier New");
                par1.FontSize(8);
                document.Save();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (DocX document = DocX.Create(Crawlspace.LogFile))
            {
                Paragraph par1 = document.InsertParagraph();
                par1.Append(logUpdate);
                par1.Font("Courier New");
                par1.FontSize(8);
                document.Save();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And how do you think someone could help here? You are missing a lot of details. What did you change exactly? How does the output looks like and how it should?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:

I checked the xceed.words.net.docx dll in the nuget manager and found there was an update. Updated to the latest and modified my using statements to reflect the update and it's now working....

```
using Image     = Xceed.Document.NET.Image;
using Paragraph = Xceed.Document.NET.Paragraph;
using Picture   = Xceed.Document.NET.Picture;
```